# Is there any way I can connect to gsheets api only through client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there any way I can connect to gsheets api only through client side javascript? Not with appscript in gsheets ,not having any webserver. For a simple desktop use. The .html/.js file just stays in my local computer. I want to fetch large data from some api(which takes lots of time) and save it gsheets.Can I do it without any webserver and just by using client side local html file? app scipts in gsheet not letting me run for more than 6 min.

Comment: Have a look at the [quickstart for client side js](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). You need to connect to a webserver at some point for authentication. this is done with [SimpleHTTPServer](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js#step_3_run_the_sample).

Comment: I am able to achieve this with python webapp. But suppose I thought I don't want even a simple server..